# d3.js split group with rotate and translate applied and calculate new translate coordinates

Tags: d3.js, svg

Given an initial rect within a group having translate and rotate transform applied, I want to split that given rectangle with the same rotation and the translation taking the rotation into account.

Below a code example to try to explain what I try to achieve.

I believe I just need to calculate the translate x,y of each new rectangle?

```js
    //Draw initial svg
    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 1000)

    // Data for the initial group with one rectangle inside
    const groupData = {width: 200, height: 100, translateX: 200, translateY: 150, rotation: 45}

    //Create the initial group
    let group1 = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'group1')

    //Append a rect to the initial group, translate and rotate
    group1.append('rect').attr('width', groupData.width).attr('height', groupData.height).attr('fill', 'blue')

    group1.attr('transform', `translate(${groupData.translateX}, ${groupData.translateY}) rotate(${groupData.rotation}, ${groupData.width / 2}, ${groupData.height / 2})`)



    // Attempt to split the initial group in equal parts based on the number of rows and columns from below
    const splitGroupData = {
      rows: 2,
      columns: 2
    }

    //Extract the data
    const {rows, columns} = splitGroupData

    // Create row and column array to dynamically split the initial group based on the split data
    const rowArray = [...Array(+rows).keys()]
    const columnArray = [...Array(+columns).keys()]

    //creates a rect inside the group 1 to split into 2 rows and 2 columns
    rowArray.forEach(row => {
      columnArray.forEach( column => {
        let newRect = group1
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", groupData.width / columns)
          .attr("height", groupData.height / rows)
          .attr("x", (groupData.width / +columns) * column)
          .attr("y", (groupData.height / +rows) * row)
          .attr("stroke", "red")
          .attr("fill", "transparent");
      })
    })

    // Trying to recreate the same rect as above but within their own group and can't figure how to calculate the right translation

    rowArray.forEach(row => {
      columnArray.forEach( column => {
          
      let newGroup = svg.append('g').attr('id', `group${column}${row}`)

      newGroup.append('rect')
        .attr('width', groupData.width / columns)
        .attr('height', groupData.height / rows)
        .attr('fill', 'orange')

        const cx = groupData.width / 2;
        const cy = groupData.height / 2;
        let tmpX = groupData.translateX + (groupData.width / +columns) * column;
        let tmpY = groupData.translateY + (groupData.height / +rows) * row;
        tmpX = tmpX - cx;
        tmpY = tmpY - cy;
        const pointX =
          tmpX * Math.cos((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) -
          tmpY * Math.sin((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
        const pointY =
          tmpX * Math.sin((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) +
          tmpY * Math.cos((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
          
        newGroup.attr('transform', `translate(${groupData.translateX + pointX}, ${groupData.translateY + pointY}) rotate(${groupData.rotation}, ${groupData.width / columns / 2}, ${groupData.height  / rows / 2})`)
          
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Now I'm able to position each new rectangle on the right position against each other. In the example in the snippet, I just want to be able to have all 4 rectangles covering the initial rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out after multiple manual tests. Not sure it is the most efficient formula but at least it works! Hope it helps someone in the same case!

```js
    //Draw initial svg
    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 1000)

    // Data for the initial group with one rectangle inside
    const groupData = {width: 200, height: 100, translateX: 200, translateY: 150, rotation: 45}

    //Create the initial group
    let group1 = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'group1')

    //Append a rect to the initial group, translate and rotate
    group1.append('rect').attr('width', groupData.width).attr('height', groupData.height).attr('fill', 'blue')

    group1.attr('transform', `translate(${groupData.translateX}, ${groupData.translateY}) rotate(${groupData.rotation}, ${groupData.width / 2}, ${groupData.height / 2})`)

    const rows = 3
    const columns = 2
    // Create row and column array to dynamically split the initial group based on the rows and columns numbers
    const rowArray = [...Array(+rows).keys()]
    const columnArray = [...Array(+columns).keys()]

    rowArray.forEach(row => {
      columnArray.forEach( column => {
          
      let newGroup = svg.append('g').attr('id', `group${column}${row}`)

      newGroup.append('rect')
        .attr('width', groupData.width / columns)
        .attr('height', groupData.height / rows)
        .attr('fill', 'orange')

        const cx = groupData.translateX + (groupData.width / columns / 2) * (columns - 1);
        const cy = groupData.translateY + (groupData.height / rows / 2) * (rows - 1);
        const tmpX = groupData.translateX + (groupData.width / columns) * column - cx;
        const tmpY = groupData.translateY + (groupData.height / rows) * row - cy;
        const pointX = tmpX * Math.cos((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) - tmpY * Math.sin((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) + cx;
        const pointY = tmpX * Math.sin((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) + tmpY * Math.cos((groupData.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) + cy;


        newGroup.attr('transform', `translate(${groupData.rotation != 0 ? pointX : groupData.translateX + (groupData.width / columns) * column}, ${groupData.rotation != 0 ? pointY : groupData.translateY + (groupData.height / rows) * row}) rotate(${groupData.rotation}, ${groupData.width / columns / 2}, ${groupData.height  / rows / 2})`)
          
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```